# Fetching data from database texbox when a comobox value is selected in datagridview?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

I want when I choose a value from a datagridview combo box to fetch from the database into a datagridview textbox. See in the image when I choose any medicine name that unitprice should be fetched from the database. How can that be done?

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection string);

            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select quantity,unitprice,totalprice from stock where medicinename='" + dataGridView1.Columns[0].ToString() + "' ", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;

            dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "quantity";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "unitprice";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "totalprice";
            con.Close();
```

[image]

Comment: Does the data absolutely have to be the most recent in the database? This approach will probably be rather slow for users, hitting the db on every combobox selection. Better would be to retrieve all the data into memory before hand then insert the right values when the medicine is selected.

Comment: can u tell me where is problem in my code ?